# Bootstrap - Draw two cards per row in mobile size

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need draw a list of rows with two cards per row in mobile version. Every card must have 3 rows (25, 50 and 25 percent) First of these rows must have 2 cells (75 / 25 percent).

One mobile screen, must fit 3 rows.

I've tried do this but I am not able to do it.
https://www.codeply.com/p/cL9RcBUMtL

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you please add a mock layout or wireframe?

Comment: Here you can see what I am trying to do. https://www.codeply.com/p/cL9RcBUMtL

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using Card-deck, just simply use row (only) and change the **"min-height"** to **"height: 100vh"**

Then Coming to 2 Cards In a Row, Try Using **"col-6"** for mobile screen.

By doing this you could able to achieve the **"3 row in mobile screen with each 2 cards"** and for other responsive use col-sm-4 for middle screen and col-md-3 for rest of the view.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="height: 100vh">
    <div class="card col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 my-3">
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center font-weight-bold align-middle">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center" style="font-size: 250%">TITULO</h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-50">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">50</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-75 col-6 text-center bg-success font-weight-bold align-middle">75</td>
                        <td class="w-25 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">25</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 my-3">
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center font-weight-bold align-middle">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center" style="font-size: 250%">TITULO</h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-50">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">50</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-75 col-6 text-center bg-success font-weight-bold align-middle">75</td>
                        <td class="w-25 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">25</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 my-3">
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center font-weight-bold align-middle">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center" style="font-size: 250%">TITULO</h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-50">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">50</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-75 col-6 text-center bg-success font-weight-bold align-middle">75</td>
                        <td class="w-25 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">25</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 my-3">
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center font-weight-bold align-middle">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center" style="font-size: 250%">TITULO</h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-50">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">50</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-75 col-6 text-center bg-success font-weight-bold align-middle">75</td>
                        <td class="w-25 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">25</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 my-3">
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center font-weight-bold align-middle">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center" style="font-size: 250%">TITULO</h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-50">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">50</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-75 col-6 text-center bg-success font-weight-bold align-middle">75</td>
                        <td class="w-25 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">25</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 my-3">
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center font-weight-bold align-middle">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center" style="font-size: 250%">TITULO</h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-50">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-100 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">50</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-25">
            <table class="h-100 w-100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-75 col-6 text-center bg-success font-weight-bold align-middle">75</td>
                        <td class="w-25 col-6 text-center bg-danger font-weight-bold align-middle">25</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great !!, I see high: 100vh means main row fills the height of the screen, but if instead of 3 rows of cards there are 2 that makes them also fill the screen and then they are higher. I need each card to occupy a third of the screen, is it possible?
I also need to put a space between each card, so that they are not close together. But if I use mx-3 then cards don't fit in one row

Thank you very much

Comment: I request you to see in mobile view, So that 3 rows of card (each row has 2 cards) can be viewed. Make sure that you are in full screen

Comment: Do you want this view to show only 2 cards in a row for all view (mobile, tablet, laptop,....)

Comment: I need to see 3 rows per page, so every row must be a third of screen. Not always will be 3 rows, could be 1, 2 or 3 rows. If there are 4 rows, 3 must be in the first page and the fourth in the second, but sizing every one one third of a page

Comment: this page is only for mobile view. Here my code  https://www.codeply.com/p/cL9RcBUMtL

Comment: If you have any picture or  UI style, that could help a lot..

Comment: something like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NoXVWBeaMupTanph9PONklZGJMRFdmMS/view?usp=drivesdk . but I want three rows per page and if there are only two rows must fit the same size

Comment: i will look into it and tell you soon

Comment: have you got your answer you are looking for?

Comment: Nice... Glad to help .

Answer (score 0):

You can go with

```
<div className="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6 video position-relative">
```

where,

1. col-lg(large)-2 means dividing 12/2 = 6 columns in desktop
   view(>992px),
2. col-md(medium)-3 means dividing 12/3 = 4 columns in tablet
   view(>768px),
3. col-sm(small)-4 means dividing 12/4 = 3 columns in small tablet
   view(>576px),
4. col-xs(extra-small)-6 means 12/6 = 2 columns in mobile view(<576px)

You can once go through the bootstrap grid system:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/